# Sitecore Multilist Datasource to new created item

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I've got a problem in Sitecore.

I've created a template with a Multilist field. What I want to do is, if I create a new item from this template the datasource of the Multilist field is set to the new created item. 
I already tried something like that.

```
datasource=$id
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Sitecore query in the `source` field of your multilist.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
query:./*
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!